# petalinux v2018.2 installation error

Tags: xilinx

I am installing Petalinux_v2018.2 on Ubuntu 2016.04.5

```
./petalinux-v2018.2.ir.run /opt/petalinux_2018.2/
```

But end with error:

```
./petalinux-v2018.2.ir.run: line 52: /opt/petalinux_2018.2/petalinux_installation_log: Permission denied
tee: /opt/petalinux_2018.2/petalinux_installation_log: Permission denied
INFO: Checking installer checksum...

tee: /opt/petalinux_2018.2/petalinux_installation_log: Permission denied
Please refer to the PetaLinux Tools Installation Guide.

Check the troubleshooting guide at the end of that manual, and if you are
unable to resolve the issue please contact customer support with file:
   /opt/petalinux_2018.2/petalinux_installation_log

tee: /opt/petalinux_2018.2/petalinux_installation_log: Permission denied
INFO: Extracting PetaLinux installer...
tar: /tmp/tmp.eeJueiu2Ol: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tee: /opt/petalinux_2018.2/petalinux_installation_log: Permission denied
ERROR: Failed to extract the PetaLinux installer. Failed to install PetaLinux Tools!
```

Any help to solve this problem will be appreciated.

When I try

`sudo  ./petalinux-v2018.2.ir.run /opt/petalinux_2018.2/`

It also prompt with error:

```
ERROR: Exiting Installer: Cannot install as root user!
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a directory somewhere else and install it to there:

```
mkdir ~/petalinux
./petalinux-*.run ~/petalinux
```

This is happening because non-root users cannot modify the contents of `/opt` and Petalinux also has a check to ensure that it's not installed by root itself since it may damage the system if used incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you cannot execute this as a root user, while the only one who has the permissions to write in the log file is the root user. Just change the permissions so that a no root user can write:

```
sudo chmod 666 petalinux_installation_log
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just debugging the same problem with Petalinux 2019.1 and my problem was that the full-featured gawk was not installed. See the blog entry below - it fixed the problem for me when installing in Ubuntu 19.10.

https://blog.lazy-evaluation.net/posts/linux/petalinux-v2019-1-ubuntu-18-04.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, fixed by:

```
sudo mkdir /opt/petalinux
sudo chown -R `whoami` /opt/petalinux
./petalinux-*.run /opt/petalinux
# Optionally: sudo chown -R root /opt/petalinux
```

Note that you cannot install petalinux in your home, then move it to /opt, it will not work. Many paths have to be defined at installation time.